# Why can't I use select * to select data rows when mysql innodb adds table write lock?

Tags: mysql, innodb

mysql version is 8.0.30. when i add table write lock, i found that the MDL lock was add .Lock type is SHARED_NO_READ_WRITE.When I execute select * in the locking transaction, the query state description is 'Waiting for table metadata lock'.But it is normal to use select + column name.

Why is this happening? What I understand is that locking transactions should be able to query table data.Please give me some advice if you know the reason.

create table sql:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `account` (
  `amount` decimal(10,0) DEFAULT '0',
  `id` int NOT NULL,
  `create_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

Reproduce sql:

```sql
set autocommit=0;
show VARIABLES like 'autocommit';

begin;
lock table account write;
-- it's working
select amount from account where id = 1;
-- blocking
select * from account where id = 1;

unlock TABLES;
commit;
```

Blocking info:

```sql
show PROCESSLIST;
```

result: Waiting for table metadata lock. SELECT * FROM `order`.`account` LIMIT 0;

```sql
SELECT OBJECT_NAME,LOCK_TYPE FROM performance_schema.metadata_locks;
```

result:

account SHARED_NO_READ_WRITE
order/account   INTENTION_EXCLUSIVE
session_status  SHARED_READ
metadata_locks  SHARED_READ

Comment: Select * is bad form anyway and should be avoided, also when you only want to update id 1 why do you lock the conplete table, write after the select FOR UPDATE so that the row(s) are locked

Comment: Thanks for your advice.This does not happen in a production environment, it is just the sql used for testing when learning innodb lock related knowledge. It is undoubtedly the best practice to only query the required columns, but I want to know the reason why unexpected blocking occurs when executing select *.

Comment: I don't believe that a SELECT *  would do behave other than SELECT a, you should check, there a lot of information that you can check like procesxslist and lock status. which you should consult, i think there will be anther process that read locks the table

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `LOCK TABLES` with InnoDB (with rare exceptions).  Instead, use `BEGIN` and `COMMIT` around any statements that need the "ACID" nature of a "transaction".

(I see no need to wrap those two `SELECTs` in a transaction.)

Also, `autocommit=0` should never be used (*in my opinion*).  It leads to forgetting to perform `COMMIT` eventually.  Instead, use only `BEGIN` and `COMMIT` to make the extent of the transaction clear.

Also, one rarely needs to stray from the default transaction isolation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm sorry that the SQL in my question is full of loopholes. It is actually used for testing when learning the principles. I want to know what causes unexpected blocking when executing select *.

Comment: @weihaogao - It is good to try things and learn from them.  A "Reference manual" tells you _everything_ that you _can_ do.  But it often fails to say what you _should_ and _should not_ do.  Sorry if my Answer was harsh; keep learning!

Comment: @weihaogao - and...  Speaking of shoulds and should nots...  See my "Rick's RoTs" (Rules of Thumb):  https://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/ricksrots